# How to use the object value in another class in Kotlin and Microsoft Oauth 2.0

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I want to use the below object in another class:

```java
private var mSingleAccountApp: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication? = null

PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(
    this,
    R.raw.auth_config_single_account,
    object : IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener {
        override fun onCreated(application: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication) {
            mSingleAccountApp = application
            // loadAccount()
        }

        override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
            //txt_log.text = exception.toString()
        }
    }
)
```

I need to call the below method from another class

```java
fun performOperationOnSignOut() {
    mSingleAccountApp!!.signOut(object : ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication.SignOutCallback {
        override fun onSignOut() {

        }

        override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
            //displayError(exception)
        }
    })
}
```

I tried to call but `mSingleAccountApp` always throws `NullPointerException`

How can I pass or use the `mSingleAccountApp` variable in another class?
`ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication` this is an interface

Comment: remove the private modifier

Comment: but how can i call the mSingleAccountApp from another class?

Comment: {name_of_object}.{name_of_variable}

Comment: Just pass the object as parameter like `loadAccount(mSingleAccountApp)`

Comment: use simpler names in your questions so we can read it

Comment: @mohsen this from microsoft oauth 2.0 , i thought any one have worked on same can help me easily

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman i passed performOperationOnSignOut from another class null pointer error is coming

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest example I could come up with:

```
//class with one property
class Foo(val name : String){
}

class Bar(){
    constructor(foo: Foo) : this() {
        //access the property of the foo object
        println(foo.name)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val foo = Foo("John Doe")
    //pass foo-object in the constructor
    val bar = Bar(foo)
}
```

see also: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomClass(var listener: ListenerAppImp){
    private var mSingleAccountApp: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication? = null


    PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(
    this,
    R.raw.auth_config_single_account,
    object : IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener {
        override fun onCreated(application: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication) {
            mSingleAccountApp = application
            listener.getAppValue(mSingleAccountApp) // todo  mSingleAccountApp Value through interface
            // loadAccount()
        }

        override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
            //txt_log.text = exception.toString()
        }
    }
    )

}

// todo for example

interface ListenerAppImp {
    fun getAppValue(mSingleAccountApp : ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication)
}

class User {
   var customClass = CustomClass(object : ListenerAppImp{
       override fun getAppValue(mSingleAccountApp: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication) {

       }
   })
}
```

> hope that may help you

Comment: Let me try :)  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your case just implement interface `ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication` in another class for your understanding let's keep class name is `Another`

```
class Another : ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          .....InitialiseYourInterfaceHere.....

   }

   override fun signOut(..yourcode...){
            .......yourcode.......
   }
}
```